# RegEx for replacing part of a string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I am trying to do an exact pattern match using the gsub/sub and replace function. I am not getting the desired response. I am trying to remove the .x and .y from the names without affecting other names.

```
name = c("company", "deriv.x", "isConfirmed.y")
new.name = gsub(".x$|.y$", "", name)
new.name
[1] "compa"       "deriv"       "isConfirmed"
```

company has become compa.

I have also tried

```
remove = c(".x", ".y")
replace(name, name %in% remove, "")
[1] "company"    "deriv.x"    "isConfirmed.y"
```

I would like the outcome to be. 
"company", "deriv", "isConfirmed"

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: `gsub("[.](x|y)$", "", name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a regex, `.` represents "any character". In order to recognize literal `.` characters, you need to escape the character, like so:

```
name <- c("company", "deriv.x", "isConfirmed.y")
new.name <- gsub("\\.x$|\\.y$", "", name)
new.name

[1] "company"     "deriv"       "isConfirmed"
```

This explains why in your original example, "company" was being transformed to "compa" (deleting the "any character of 'n', followed by a 'y' and end of string").

Onyambu's comment would also work, since within the `[ ]` portion of a regex, `.` is interpreted literally.

```
gsub("[.](x|y)$", "", name)
```

Comment: Thank you jdobres. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here we can have a simple expression that removes the undesired `.` and anything after that:

```
(.+?)(?:\..+)?
```

or for exact match:

```
(.+?)(?:\.x|\.y)?
```

#### R Test

Your code might look like something similar to:

```
gsub("(.+?)(?:\\..+)?", "\\1", "deriv.x")
```

or

```
gsub("(.+?)(?:\.x|\.y)?", "\\1", "deriv.x")
```

#### [R Demo](https://ideone.com/AIdAZA)

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/yO6Aa9/1/)

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/7S4yfs/1/)

#### Description

Here, we are having a capturing group `(.+?)`, where our desired output is and a non-capturing group `(?:\..+)?` which swipes everything after the undesired `.`.

Comment: This seems to be written in JavaScript, not R.

Answer (score 1):

The dot matches any character except a newline ao `.x$|.y$` would also match the `ny` in `company`

There is no need for any grouping structure to match a dot followed by x or y. You could match a dot and match either x or y using a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html):

```
\\.[xy]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrjVRJ/1) | [R demo](https://ideone.com/rKrDVx)

And replace with an empty string:

```
name = c("company", "deriv.x", "isConfirmed.y")
new.name = gsub("\\.[xy]", "", name)
new.name
```

Result

```
[1] "company"     "deriv"       "isConfirmed"
```